# Constraint to not allow a number to be more than one time in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm developing a solution with SQL Server 2012 SP2.

I'm wondering if I can do the following adding some kind of restriction to a table's column.

I will have a column that can store `tinyint` values (from 1 to 5). This table will have a lot of rows.

The restriction is that you can have number 5 repeated more than one time, but the rest of the numbers couldn't be repeated. In other words, only one row could have number 1, only one row could have number 2, or 3 or 4. But many rows could have number 5.

Is there anyway to do that in SQL? (like an UNIQUE constraint).

Now I'm doing it in a stored procedure doing select count() ... and if statements.

Comment: @marc_s maybe, but I'm not a SQL expert. Thanks.

Comment: Misread your question - sorry :-) But @GiorgosBetsos has the perfect answer, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a unique *filtered* index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IDX_UQ_Col
ON mytable(myCol)
WHERE myCol <> 5
```